# Compiling LESS with mapping. How to set relative path for sources?

Tags: css, compilation, less, source-maps

I have some problems with creating a proper `.map` file.
I compile by this way:

```
lessc --source-map=styles.map styles.less styles.css
```

The problem is that the path to the sources files is a full local path. It looks like this (quote from the beginning of `styles.map`):

> {"version":3,"sources":["**C:/xampp/htdocs/Projects/TestSite**/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/bower_components/bootstrap/less/normalize.less"
>   ...

After uploading to server, all the paths to source files are accepted in a wrong way.
If I replace all `C:/xampp/htdocs/Projects/TestSite` with an empty string, it becomes well.
What settings should I do to get a right `.map` file?
I tested `--source-map-less-inline`;  it includes all of the Less files in to the sourcemap, so it goes well, but by this way the  `.map` file becomes very big.

Comment: See [`--source-map-basepath`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-source-map-basepath).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thank you very much! It works well now.